# How to update a global Rails variable in some sort of job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a global variable in one of my Rails initializer config/initializers/globals.rb. This variable is simply a list, set to the members of a Redis set.

```
$listOfBannedDomains = $redis.smembers("banned_domains")
```

The Redis set gets updated once in awhile. How can I update $listOfBannedDomains with what's in the Redis set once every X hours without restarting my Rails app?

Note that I do not want to read from the Redis set in real-time.

Comment: I'm curious about why you don't want to read from redis everytime when $listOfBannedDomains is accessed?

Comment: because it could potentially have 1 billion items in it.

Comment: Added an answer below to let your constant be updated asynchronously without blocking the Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) for this and utilize it's [perioidic timer](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/eventmachine/eventmachine/EventMachine#add_periodic_timer-class_method) to do that asynchronously in an evented loop.

Create a new rails initializer - `config/initializers/redis_periodic.rb`

```
$listOfBannedDomains = $redis.smembers("banned_domains")

Thread.new { EM.run } unless EM.reactor_running? # Run the EventMachine reactor if it's not running already in a new thread.
Signal.trap("INT")  { EM.stop }
Signal.trap("TERM") { EM.stop }

# Add a periodic timer:
time_interval = 5 #seconds
EM.add_perioidic_timer(time_interval) do
  # Update the constant by re-reading from redis
  $listOfBannedDomains = $redis.smembers("banned_domains")
end
```

Note: This won't block your main Rails thread from requests and will allow you do that operation asynchronously, per rails instance. You can add extra conditions in initializer to exclude this from happening in Rake(if required).

Comment: This EM thread will stop running I assume if the Rails thread exits?

Comment: Good point. missed that. Added the code for same. The recommended way to do is to trap signals and ask EM to stop when main thread exits.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper method for returning this variable. You can add some additional variable for storing time of last update. If time from last update is more than X hours update the value from Redis.